# Multiple populate in one filed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, ref, mongoose-populate

In my Transaction Array field I have two different Object Id. One is Deposit and another one is Withdraw. And I need to populate both Object Id.

For Example:-

```
Transaction: [
 { Object id of Deposit },
 { Object id of Withdraw }
]
```

Does it every possible to populate this array ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the population, but you can create an aggregation pipeline with 2 `$lookup` stages and then finally you add the resulting arrays on a `$project` stage. Will be easier to provide more insightful example if you provide the schemas for the collections.

The aggregation pipeline should be something like this.

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'Deposit', //assuming the collection is called like this
      'localField': 'Transaction', 
      'foreignField': '_id', //assuming the _id is the foreign field
      'as': 'resultDeposit'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'Withdraw', 
      'localField': 'Transaction', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'resultWithdraw'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'Transaction': {
        '$concatArrays': [
          '$resultDeposit', '$resultWithdraw'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

First creating an temporarily array called `resultDeposit`, then creating a temporary array called `resultWithdraw` and finally adding both as the original array

Comment: Thanks Fernando, With the help of aggregation pipeline It can be solve. But does it ever possible to solve it with  **populate**  `ref/ refPath ` ?